# Как обратиться к MySQL по внешнему ip?

Tags: mysql, ip

Узнал я внешний ip через [2ip](http://2ip.ru/). Как я могу подключиться к `MySQL`, запущенной на моём ПК через внешний ip?

PS Если я пробую подключится так: `mysql -u "user" -p -h ip(с 2ip)`, то получаю ошибку: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (115)`

Comment: С вероятностью 99% вы узнали выходной ip провайдера. С вероятностью 99.9% у провайдера настроен файрвол который всё равно не пропускает входящие запросы

Comment: @AlexeyTen, то есть, без подключения услуги статичного ip мне никак не подключиться к своей БД?

Comment: Порты пробросил, на роутере? Не подключается только к mysql? p.s у mysql, возможно, есть диапазон ип, которые она слушает, в конфиге.

Comment: @Lasna1, MySQL прослушивает порт 3306. Простите, если тупой вопрос, но как делать проброс портов?

Comment: @DGDays `sudo ufw allow PORT/tcp`

Comment: @DGDays. Навреное в этом и проблема... Вы за nat. Вам на роутере нужно открыть порт: типа: Входящий: 3306 Локальный: 3306, и локальный ип.... Это просто, гляньте на модель своего роутера и псмотрите в интернете.

Comment: @Lasna1, нашёл уже как пробросить, но всё равно ничего не пашет

Comment: Тогда, в конфиге mysql тебе нужно слушатель подправить. Он, наверное, только локалку слушает.

Comment: @Lasna1, уже разобрался) В keenetic можно под все доступные сети настроить прослушку, а я не заметил этого пункта XD